# Possible to write files from Windows application directly to Android SD card?

Tags: android, windows, sd-card

I'm looking for a way to write a file from a Windows application to an Android device SD card over a USB connection.  To do this, I will need to obtain the drive letter of the SD card, and it's mount point.  My Windows application is written in C++, so I'm most hoping for a solution in C++.  If not possible, perhaps there is a Java solution which can then be placed in a C++ wrapper to be called by my application's code.

I've searched around and come up with a few ideas but nothing seems to work yet.  First, I came across Google's documentation on a method,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), but my assumption is that since this is part of the Android SDK, it is only usable from an application residing on an Android device.  Secondly, I came across some functions in Windows' native API (WinBase.h primarily), which provides a way of locating all drives and their corresponding letters, but even if I can get this information, I don't know how to  determine which of these is the connected Android device's SD card.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To clarify a bit, when connecting my device to my machine, two external devices are recognized.  One represents the internal storage of the device, the second represents the SD card.  I need to be able to detect which of these two is the SD card in order to transfer the file over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a windows application expert but if you can use system calls in your C++ program to call adb.exe, then you can execute adb commands directly to the device.

For example if you can execute "adb.exe devices" you can get a list of all android devices currently attached to the computer. From there, you can use any adb commands to push files onto the device.

More information on the adb commands here: [ADB wiki](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=ADB)

What you're looking for is probably doing an `adb devices` in combination with `adb push <your file> /sdcard/<file on sdcard>`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I actually want to avoid having to require the end-user to install ADB in order for the application to work.

Comment: Marking Otra's answer as correct.  This seems impossible from a Windows app unless it's working in conjunction with ADB.

Comment: if adb can do it, and its a windows app, then  it must be possible to write a windows app to do it! strange there isn't more good info about this

Comment: adb push does work, i wonder, is it ok to ship adb with my app?